# Invalid Hyperlink: Malformed URI is embedded as a hyperlink in the document

Tags: c#, openxml, excel-addins

I'm using the OpenXml namespace in my application. I'm using this to read the XML within an Excel file. This works fine with certain excel files but on others I get a run time error saying

> Invalid Hyperlink: Malformed URI is embedded as a hyperlink in the document.

I get the run time on the following line

```
using (var spreadsheet = 
      DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePathCopy, true))
```

I'm not sure why it works for some Excel files and doesn't work on others.

Comment: Looks like a common issue. This might help: http://ericwhite.com/blog/handling-invalid-hyperlinks-openxmlpackageexception-in-the-open-xml-sdk/

Answer (score 14):

#### Solution is from Eric White's [blog post](http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/handling-invalid-hyperlinks-openxmlpackageexception-in-the-open-xml-sdk/)

1. Import OpenXmlPowerTools from Nuget and use it.

   ```
   using OpenXmlPowerTools;
   ```

   The method needed is `OpenXmlPowerTools.UriFixer.FixInvalidUri`, or you could copy the `UriFixer` class from the link.

2. Add the `FixUri()` method to handle the broken URI's with a new defined URI.

   ```
   private static Uri FixUri(string brokenUri)
   {
       return new Uri("http://broken-link/");
   }
   ```

3. Add code to open the document, if the exception occurs it fixes the URI's and re-opens the fixed document.

   ```
   WordprocessingDocument wDoc;
   try
   {
       using (wDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(newFileName, true))
       {
           //Try do something
       }
   }
   catch (OpenXmlPackageException e)
   {
       if (e.ToString().Contains("Invalid Hyperlink"))
       {
           using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
           {
               //Fix problematic URI's
               UriFixer.FixInvalidUri(fs, brokenUri => FixUri(brokenUri));
           }
           using (wDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(newFileName, true))
           {
               //Do something without error
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution.  Your answer worked perfectly for me!

Comment: I would use `catch (OpenXmlPackageException e) when (e.InnerException is UriFormatException)` instead of relying on the exception message which could change (for localization, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You can also fix the Excel worksheet in Excel with a quick VB script:

Easy way to remove Hyperlinks from Excel sheet:

- Open worksheet.
- Press Alt + F11 to open the VB macro editor.
- Add the VB sub below, then Save. If you don't want to save the macro - since you're probably only doing this once - ignore the macro-free worksheet errors if prompted.
- Close, then go to Macros and run the macro.

  Sub RemoveHyperlinks()

  ' Remove all hyperlinks from the active sheet.
  ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Delete

  End Sub

Based on: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=4&v=w8LyIJWIGj0&feature=emb_title