# How to open word document with corrupted data?

Tags: c#, office-interop, word-interop

I am trying to create a C# .net window application, functionality is to open Word document and facing issue when word document contains an invalid link and through exception. 
Please find below error : 
 **Message=Invalid Hyperlink: Malformed URI is embedded as a hyperlink in the document.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid Hyperlink: Malformed URI is embedded as a hyperlink in the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40979946/invalid-hyperlink-malformed-uri-is-embedded-as-a-hyperlink-in-the-document)

Comment: that should help : http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/handling-invalid-hyperlinks-openxmlpackageexception-in-the-open-xml-sdk/ :D